# How are same named input tags represented on the server side

Tags: html, web-standards

While looking at some source code for different forms I ran across this piece of code

```
<input class="" id="Delivery_HasShippingAddress" name="Delivery.HasShippingAddress" tabindex="11" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Delivery.HasShippingAddress" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

which belongs to **the same** form. As you can see there are two `input` tags with the same name though different type and id. If the form is submitted [tamper data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) lists them "both" as POSTDATA:

```
Delivery.HasShippingAddress=true
Delivery.HasShippingAddress=false
```

**I am now wondering how this request would be processed?**

Does the Server override the first value with the second or does the first value received dominate or are maybe both values listed (would be weird though)?

Comment: If I remember right, you'll get an array of values

Comment: @Crackertastic Quentin claims that there is no standard way of processing it. I'd prefer to accept an answer containing either a source telling me how to process them conforming the standard or a source telling me that there is none

Comment: @Sim That is fine, I don't know the answer with certainty, which is why I didn't write up an answer.  I had also worded my previous comment (now deleted) incorrectly.  PHP overwrites fields of the same name.  But that is not to say that another language does it different, or that you couldn't configure said language to do it any particular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will encode the data as a string. Typically:

```
Delivery.HasShippingAddress=true&Delivery.HasShippingAddress=false
```

What happens on the server depends on your form processing library. Usually it will decode [according to this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-decoding-algorithm). Then it will present the data to the programmer.

Some will present an array of values. Some will present just one of the values. Some might do either depending on the function you call.

Comment: so there is no standard on how to process those?

Comment: [There is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-decoding-algorithm), but that doesn't stop PHP (at least) from discarding some of the data.

Comment: oh great. Please edit this into your answer and I'll accept it.